# How to process mutiple forms using one page with functions?

Tags: php, forms, function

So you can include for example `functions.php` in your file and then you can use different functions in that page to validate user input.

But how can I process multiple forms using the same file?

Example:

```
include formprocessor.php
```

formprocessor would contain all the functions related to each form:

```
Form A action=formAfunction()
Form B action=formBfunction()
Form C action=formCfunction()
```

Can formprocessor.php contain a function specifically for handling each form? 
Each form would have their own function to process their data.

If this is possible it is way more convenient than having a processor file for each form on a site. 10 forms 10 processing files?

Or 10 forms 1 processing file.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an input type=hidden that contains a name for each form, then in your form processor, read the name that was submitted and go to the specific part of the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a name to the submit button for each form in html

```
<form method='post' ... >
   ....
   <input type='submit' name='formA' ...>
</form>

<form method='post' ... >
   ....
   <input type='submit' name='formB' ...>
</form>
```

Then use something like this in your php code to handle it:

```
if(isset($_POST['formA'])){
   formAfunction(); //handle formA
}elseif(isset($_POST['formB'])){
   formBfunction(); //handle formB
} //.... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden process inside your form. IE

```
<form id = "login" action = "calls.php" method = "POST">
<input id="process" name="process" type="hidden" value="loginpr">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<form id = "logout" action = "calls.php" method= "POST">
<input id="process" name="process" type="hidden" value="logoutpr">
<input type="submit>
</form>
```

Then you have your calls.php file which switches based off the the process called.

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])){
       switch($_POST['process']) {
               case 'loginpr':
               loginfunction();
               break;
               case 'logoutpr':
               logoutfunction();
               break;
       }
    }
else { echo "The process is not linked within this form"; }
```

calls.php would be your formproccessor.php file